# Codeigniter save form_multiselect into database and set_value

Tags: php, codeigniter

i try to save a form_multiselect but it dont save and the value dont select. I hope you can help me please.

Edit: Its working now but only with a single select. I cant select more as one options.

I try this

view

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="field-1"> Team</label>

                <div class="col-sm-4">

                <?= form_multiselect('teams_id[]', dd2menu('teams', array('teams_id' => 'title')), set_value('teams_id[]', $item->teams_id), 'class="form-control"') ?>

                </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public function manage($id = NULL) {
        $data = array();

        if ($id) {
            $this->{$this->model}->{$this->_primary_key} = $id;
            $data['item'] = $this->{$this->model}->get();
            if (!$data['item'])
                show_404();
        } else {
            $data['item'] = new Std();
        }


$this->load->library("form_validation");
$this->{$this->model}->custom_select = 'users.*, teams.title as teams';
$this->{$this->model}->joins = array( 'teams' => array('teams.teams_id = users.teams_id', 'inner'));

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
$this->load->view($this->module . '/manage', $data);

else {

$this->users_model->teams_id = $this->input->post('teams_id');

 $this->{$this->model}->save();
            redirect('admin/' . $this->module);
        }
    }
```

Model

```
class Users_model extends CI_model
{
    public $_table = 'users';
    public $_primary_keys = array('user_id');
}
```

I cant find the error because its working if i one select. But i can select more as one options.

Comment: you can refer this link for your reference  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836390/set-multiple-values-as-selected-in-form-multiselect-in-codeigniter

Comment: I saw this befor but it was not working for me. I can save it as single. But i cant save 2 or more options

Comment: Please post full code controller and view file.

Comment: i edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

If found the fix in the other code from NikuNi.

Now its save 1 or 1,2 in the Database.

Controller

```
if( is_array( $this->input->post('teams_id') ) ) {
            $this->{$this->model}->teams_id = join(",", $this->input->post('teams_id'));
            } else {
            $this->{$this->model}->teams_id = $this->input->post('teams_id');   
            }

$this->form_validation->set_rules('teams_id[]', 'teams_id', 'trim');
```